# Is arousal to shemale porn by straight men in "A Billion Wicked Thoughts" exemplifying situational sexual behaviour?

Tags: sexuality, transgender

## A Billion Wicked Thoughts

Over ten years ago Ogi Ogas and Sai Gaddam published a book, *A Billion Wicked Thoughts*. They did not publish any academic papers on their research, but Ogi and Sai have given a handful of public appearances where they describe their work.

- [A Billion Wicked Thoughts | Ogi Ogas | Talks at Google](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p-A8GvUehq4)

> And I'm also going to explain one of the most popular erotic interests for men, which is shemale porn. You may or may not be surprised to hear that shemale porn is one of the most popular kinds of erotica for heterosexual men all around the world, in every country in the world. And it's favored by heterosexual men, not gay men. Gay men are not very interested at all in shemale porn. Some bisexual men are interested, but its definitely dominated by heterosexual men.

- [Ogi Ogas and Sai Gaddam - Searching for Sex](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sPJQbB2o8Es)

> A great example of a male's erotic illusion is shemale porn. Now you might be surprised to hear that shemale porn is actually one of the most popular genres of pornography all across plant. One of the top 10 most popular genres of porn for heterosexual men. Heterosexual men form the main audience for shemale porn.

- [Sai Gaddam: Sexual urges and internet searches](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4a45YKqI-2I)
- [Episode 169--The Mountain Top--A Billion Wicked Thoughts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jeqjqGimREU)
- [Keen On... Ogi Ogas: A Billion Wicked Thoughts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9XDwoK7h8PM)
- [Keen On... Ogi Ogas: Online Deviance and Perversions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DdavXwv-6FM)

One of the unusual findings is that a lot of people (they infer men) watch shemale porn (or similarly trans porn, or futanari). What is even more unusual in conjunction with this is that such men were inferred to be mostly heterosexual men.

## Situational Sexual Behaviour

Wikipedia defines [situational sexual behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Situational_sexual_behavior):

> Situational sexual behavior differs from that which the person normally exhibits, due to a social environment that in some way permits, encourages, or compels the behavior in question.

Pyschology Wiki provides [a definition](https://psychology.fandom.com/wiki/Situational_sexual_behavior):

> Situational sexual behavior is sexual behavior of a kind that is different from what is usual for that person (or from what that person normally exhibits) due to a social environment that permits, encourages, or compels those acts.

## Question

Is arousal to shemale porn by straight men in "A Billion Wicked Thoughts" exemplifying situational sexual behaviour?

Comment: [Aguilar 2012](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/10.1177/0891241612464886) gives some literature review.